# Which extant ALGOL-60 compilers fully support numeric labels?

Tags: programming, compilers, algol

This question is prompted by [a related one](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/20369/4025) by texdr.aft. It turns out that the [Revised report on Algol-60](http://thecorememory.com/Algol60RevisedReport.pdf) allowed numeric labels (3.5.1, page 15),

> <label> ::= <identifier> | <unsigned integer>

as opposed to the later [Modified Report](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.104.1483&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (3.5.1, page 17),

> <label> ::= <identifier>

The rationale for the eventual restriction is quoted from the question referred above:

> Here is what Dahlstrand, Goteborg, and Naur have to say about this in Algol Bulletin [AB10.3](http://archive.computerhistory.org/resources/text/algol/algol_bulletin/A10/P3.HTM).
>
> > The admission of integers as labels will produce some peculiar possibilities, like the following:
>
> > **procedure** *Pop*(*Q*); **procedure** *Q*; **begin** … *Q*(3); … **end**;
> > **procedure** *Pip*(*A*); **label** *A*; **begin** … **go** **to** *A*; … **end**;
> > **procedure** *Pap*(*B*); **real** *B*; **begin** … *q* ≔ *B*; **end**;
> > *Pop*(*Pap*);
> > *Pop*(*Pip*);
>
> Evidently the number 3 appearing within the body of procedure *Pop* will in the first of these two procedure statements be used as a number, while in the second it will be used as a label.
>
> We do not want to suggest any formal change of the language, since in spite of the peculiarity the above example is well defined. On the other hand we do want to disrecommend the use of integers in labels in actual programs. We would like to see them die from disuse. That we do not accept them in our translators goes without saying.

There is a retro-compiler which accepts the code demonstrating the possibility (Algol-BESM-6):

```
   1.   _BEGIN
   2.  _PROCEDURE POP(Q); _PROCEDURE Q;
   3.  _BEGIN Q(3); _END;
   4.
   5.  _PROCEDURE PIP(A); _LABEL A;
   6.  _BEGIN _GOTO A; _END;
   7.
   8.  _PROCEDURE PAP(B); _INTEGER B;
   9.  _BEGIN OUTPUT(‘T’, ‘INTEGER ’, ‘ZD’, B) _END;
  10.
  11.  POP(PAP);
  12.  _IF _FALSE _THEN 3: OUTPUT(‘T’, ‘ LABEL 3’) _ELSE POP(PIP);
  13.  _END
```

prints `INTEGER 3 LABEL 3`.

A recent implementation of Algol-60, [MARST](https://www.gnu.org/software/marst/) specifically mentions that the supported language revision is according to the Modified Report, and errors out with *invalid use unsigned integer `3' as a label*

Another example, from [a Donald Knuth's paper](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Enecula/Papers/KnuthTroubleAlgol.pdf#page=5) is compiled successfully by the Algol-BESM-6 compiler, but some  error checks are missing:

```
   1.   _BEGIN _PROCEDURE P(Q); _IF B(Q) _THEN G(Q);
   2.  _PROCEDURE G(Q); _GOTO Q;
   3.  _BOOLEAN _PROCEDURE B(Q); B := Q < 5;
   4.  P(3);
   5.  OUTPUT(‘T’, ‘--- ’);
   6.  1: OUTPUT(‘T’, ‘ONE ’);
   7.  2: OUTPUT(‘T’, ‘TWO ’);
   8.  3: OUTPUT(‘T’, ‘THREE ’);
   9.  4: OUTPUT(‘T’, ‘FOUR’);
  10.  OUTPUT(‘/’);
  11.  _END
```

works and prints `THREE FOUR`, `P(2)` would print `TWO THREE FOUR`, etc. (`P(5)` or greater would print `--- ONE TWO THREE FOUR`). However, `P(0)` would compile but crash at runtime, as well as `P(1+1)`, etc.

Is there another surviving Algol-60 compiler for any of the Western computers which is a) based on the Revised Report, thus allows numeric labels, and b) is able to compile the peculiar construct correctly?

Comment: Not an answer, but I was browsing the Algol Bulletins.   [AB19.1.2](https://archive.computerhistory.org/resources/text/algol/algol_bulletin/A19/P12.HTM) mentions Alcor Illinois 7090 as being  the full language 'except for own'. The [user manual](http://bitsavers.org/pdf/univOfIllinoisUrbana/alcor/Purdue_ALCOR_Users_Manual_Apr65.pdf) does not mention integer labels one way or another. And of course the key attribute was "extant", about which I have doubts.

Comment: @another-dave *Faute de mieux*, any published evidence of a compiler able to support the construct in question would be accepted.

Comment: The problems with numeric labels are discussed in great detail in Donald Knuth's "[The remaining trouble spots in in Algol 60](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~necula/Papers/KnuthTroubleAlgol.pdf#page=5)". This isn't an answer, but the paper provides a more explicit rationale for not implementing the feature.

Comment: @texdr.aft Thanks! The Algol BESM-6 compiler seems to handle at least some of the constructs described there.

Comment: @texdr.aft Regarding Knuth's paper: the first example after "The author has shown the following procedure..." (page 5 of the PDF) is malformed, as expected. The second example ("Is this now valid?") is valid and executes correctly as far as the argument is an integer literal AND corresponds to a declared label; otherwise the program compiles successfully but loses control at runtime.
I have not realized before that Algol procedures are effectively templates.

Comment: @LeoB. - at the time, it seems they were still figuring out the difference between open subroutines and closed subroutines.  The Algol 60 **procedure** is somewhere in between, because of the way it is described,. From memory, IAL (Algol 58) had open subroutines via the **do** mechanism,

Comment: To my mind, the trouble with the pip/pap/pop example arises from the underspecification of the formal parameter Q. It's a procedure, but a procedure of what arguments, exactly?  The syntax does not allow us to say.

Comment: “… a complex document such as the ALGOL 60 Report (roughly 75 typewritten pages…)”. Me: stares in confusion at the C++ Standard

Comment: @another-dave  Theoretically, the decision could be to treat a procedure as open if it could not be compiled as closed at the point of definition. Thus `POP` becomes an open procedure, and there is no trouble. Why there are runtime errors in the second example instead of compile time diagnostics is a surprise.

Comment: Is the source code for the BESM-6 compiler available?

Comment: @texdr.aft No, just the executable binary. Even if it were, it would be, at best, some inscrutable *autocode*; sparsely, if at all, commented. I wish for someone well-versed in Radare2 or Ghidra to create an architecture definition, allowing at least to glean into such compilers. So far, personally, I was only able to decompile two Pascal compilers which were known to be self-hosting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Algol 60 compiler for the Electrologica X8](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/ALGOL/algol60impl/#X8_MC) was such an implementation. One of its authors wrote [a report](https://ir.cwi.nl/pub/13677) describing the differences between the X8 compiler and an earlier Algol compiler for the Electrologica X1, which did not support numeric labels; section 5.2.6 discusses how labels and designational expressions in general were handled.

The X8 compiler was written in Algol 60, and its source code survives in the form of a [truly gorgeous listing](https://ir.cwi.nl/pub/13070/), presumably produced by a Flexowriter.

Comment: Incidentally, the code uses the names *sub* and *bus* for `[` and `]`. I would assume this was influenced by Algol 68, which [uses the same terminology](https://jmvdveer.home.xs4all.nl/en.post.algol-68-revised-report.html#941f), but the X8 compiler [predates](https://ir.cwi.nl/pub/9529) the development of Algol 68. Were “sub” and “bus” common names at the time?

Comment: The listing is gorgeous indeed. Theoretically, the compiler can be revived by implementing an interpreter (thus, the X8 compiler is *almost* extant). Unfortunately, the list of error messages appears to be missing. I had some doubts about originality of the BESM-6 compiler because its Russian error messages are unusually verbose, compared to terse messages of other compilers, and the phrasing of some messages is unnatural, suggesting calquing from another language. If it is so, the source was not the X8 compiler: I've experimented with a test case on page 21 of the PDF and got only one error.

Comment: @texdr.aft This is just a guess.  Presumably there would have been a working committee for Algol68 prior to 1968 and the idea of statements ending with the keywords spelt backwards were thrown around at that time.  It is possible that one of the people in the committee was involved with the X8 compiler.

Comment: @LeoB. There is a list of errors in this manual: https://ir.cwi.nl/pub/9203

Comment: @LeoB. Actually, I think it is *fully* extant, since in the comparison report I linked to the author describes measurements he made running the compiler on an emulator (which is, however, unfortunately not publicly available).

Comment: FYI I made an effort to rekey that listing from the PDF scan - see https://gtoal.com/languages/algol60/x8algol/x8algol.a60.html and the parent https://gtoal.com/languages/algol60/x8algol/ for more info.  Might be a starting place for a translation to C eg with jff-a2c?

Comment: @GrahamToal Very nice work.